# How to use RabbitMQ as a Message Broker and Kafka as the Event Bus handler on the same Nest.js project?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, nestjs

I need to use RabbitMQ and Kafka together. RabbitMQ will be responsible for retrieving necessary datas one microservices to another via Gateway(A microservice) so they won't be communicating point-to-point. Kafka will be used to publish the events like "UserCreated" and microservices which are already subbed and authorized will act according to event. The confusing part for me is here:

```
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.RMQ,
      options: {
        urls: ['amqp://localhost:5672'],
        queue: 'api_gateway_queue',
        queueOptions: {
          durable: false,
        },
      },
    }
  );
```

@nestjs/microservices needs to have a property named transport which can be TCP, Kafka, RabbitMQ etc. So I think it might restrict me when I try to use two of them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is a [hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application).

Create multiple microservices and attach them to the `app`, via `app.connectMicroservice` rather than using a Factory, then start them all together with `app.startAllMicroservices()`.

Alternatively, you could use Kafka Connect outside of Nest to ingest RabbitMQ events directly into Kafka, then setup only Kafka microservice.